# What is the order of execution in this code in C (1< recursions)

Tags: c, recursion

```
#include <stdio.h>

int zad1(int k) {
    if (k <= 2) 
        return 0;
    printf("k = %d\n", k);
    zad1(--k);
    zad1(k - 1);
    printf("k = %d\n", k);
}

void main() {
    zad1(4);
}
```

I'm a student and we use GCC compiler (CodeBlocks), I do get the `k=4` and `k=3` output, but what happens then? I'm a beginner so I'd love a really dumbed down explanation of the exact order of execution. Also excuse my English since it's not my first language so I'm not sure whether I'm getting the terms right.

Comment: Welcome to SO. As a beginner you should get used to apply proper formatting to your code. Indentation should always reflect the logical structure of your code.

Comment: Getting into recursion is always fun. You could start using a debugger and follow each step of your program. Watch all variables while you execute step by step. Or you can use pen&paper to manually walk through the code. This should result in some insights about how it works.

Comment: In addition to debugging, here is another way to observe what is happening -- you can [get "happy" with `printf()`](https://godbolt.org/z/zxrvfd6dP).   SO will be quick to point out, this won't always be a suitable thing to do, and so I don't dare post it as an answer.  But for a "quick and dirty" solution, printf() of values throughout code can be very illustrative and explanatory and often quickly.  Even large IT companies do this in their logging -- I have seen it.

Comment: Not all paths through the `zad1` function return a value, and the returned value is never used, so I think you should change the return type from `int` to `void` (`void zad1(int k){`) and change `return 0;` to `return;`. Also `void main()` should be `int main()`.

Comment: Regarding missing return values: Your compiler should show you some warning that not all path return a value. Whenever the compiler found something and reports it to you, you should not ignore it. Read it, try to understand it and fix it. If your compiler did not show a warning, you need to increase diagnostics level. For GCC use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: For a good question it is useful to include complete and exact output. You state that you get `k=4` and `k=3` but I doubt that this is complete. You should see another line with `k=3`. Such details are important.

Answer (score 2):

As others pointed out in the comments, you could see the behavior of your program by either using a debugger or using `"printf()"`.

But to answer your question specifically here is what happens to your code:

1. `zad1(4)` is called from the `main` function
2. For`zad1(4)`, it prints "k=4" and calls `zad(--k);`, while "k" is decremented to 3.
3. For`zad1(3)`, it prints "k=3" and calls `zad(--k);`, while "k" is decremented to 2.

As you mentioned, you understood what happened up to this point. Let's continue:

4. For `zad1(2)`, the `if` statement is triggered and immediately **returns** without printing **anything**.

This call is now finished so the control goes back to the previous one which is `zad1(3)`.

5. `zad1(k-1)` is called with `k-1` being 3-1 = 2.
6. Now, we have `zad1(2)` which prints "k=2" since the second occurrence of the `print` statement is triggered (*see comment by @chqrlie for more detailed explanation*).

This call is now also finished so the control goes back to the initial one which is `zad1(4)`.

7. It executes the second occurrence of the `print` statement, and it prints "k=3".

So, the original call is completed and the control goes back to the `main` function.

I hope that helped ;)

*Edit: Corrected step 6.*

Comment: *Now, we have `zad1(2)` which prints `"k=2"` (since the `if` statement is triggered) and returns.*  Not exactly: `zad1(2)` is called and the `if` statement makes it return immediately back to the caller where the statement , then `zad1(k-1)` is called, ie `zad1(1)`, which returns immediately, then finally `printf("k = %d\n", k);` outputs `k = 2` and returns to its caller, the initial call to `zad1(4)`, where `k` has been decremented to `3` and the final `printf("k = %d\n", k);` outputs `k=3`.